# How to get all black fridays in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, date

I'm solving a problem where in the question is you should get all the list of `black fridays` from the year 2000 to 2011. So how to do that in `vb.net`? Any help?

Comment: Based on the title, and if you are using `Console`: `Dim dte = New DateTime(2000,1,1): Do While dte.Year <= 2011: If dte.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday Then Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Black Else Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White: Console.WriteLine(dte): dte = dte.AddDays(1): Loop`. The Fridays will be completely black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrote this code. Tested in all conditions. Hope it helps. Good Luck :)

```
    Dim BlackFridayList As String = ""
    Dim dt As Date
    Dim weeknumber As Integer = 1


    For i = 2000 To 2011
        dt = New Date(i, 11, 1)
        weeknumber = 1
        ' find first friday
        While dt.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Friday
            dt = dt.AddDays(1)
            weeknumber = weeknumber + 1
        End While


        If weeknumber = 1 And (dt.Day + 28 < Date.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month)) Then
            ' add four weeks
            dt = dt.AddDays(28)
        Else
            ' add three weeks
            dt = dt.AddDays(21)
        End If

        BlackFridayList = BlackFridayList & dt.ToLongDateString & vbCrLf
    Next

    MsgBox(BlackFridayList) 'List of all black fridays
```

Answer (score 1):

Black Friday is the day after the fourth Thursday of November. You can determine the dates for those years using DateTime functions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Function BlackFriday(Year as Integer) As DateTime
    Dim november1 = New DateTime(Year, 11, 1)
    Dim firstThursday = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(Function(x) november1.AddDays(x)).First(Function(x) x.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Thursday)
    Return firstThursday.AddDays(22)
End Function
```

And to use it:

```
Dim blackFridays = Enumerable.Range(2000,12).Select(Function(year) BlackFriday(year)).ToList
```